# Adding points array

Tags: arrays

Does anyone know how to add Point values to an array?

Comment: Can't you just use an array of points and then cast the X and Y values to doubles if/when you need to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you want the array to be of type `double`? You could just use a `Point` array;

```
Point[] points = new Point[2];
points[0] = new Point(15,15);
points[1] = new Point(200,220);

double someResult = (points[0].x - points[1].x)  * (points[0].y - points[1].y);
```

Or to loop over them;

```
for (int i = 0; i < points.Lenght; i++)
{
      // do something with points[i]
}
```

Or with a list;

```
List<Point> points = new List<Point>();
points.Add(new Point(1,1)); //ect
```

or

```
List<Point> points = new { new Point(1,1), new point(2,2) //ect };

foreach (Point p in points)
{
    // do something with p
}
```

Some random LINQ that you might favor over a loop;

```
double xTotal = points.Aggregate((c, n) => c.x + n.y); // gives sum or all x values
double yTotal = points.Aggregate((c, n) => c.y + n.y);
```

When I add two Point to an array, does that mean that the array will hold 4 values?

Sort of. The array would hold two `Point` instances. Each of those have an `x` and a `y` value but generally you would say the array is holding 2 values. If you're just looking to group 4 doubles you may not want to use `Point`'s at all. You could declare a struct like;

```
public struct Rect
{
    double a;
    double b;
    double c;
    double d;
}
```

and have your 4 doubles grouped together more nicely. Or you could use a `Tuple<double, double, double, double>` though most developers would probably find that a bit odd (hey, I like them at least). However, it's read only.

```
var tuple = new Tuple<double, double, double, double(1, 2, 3, 4);
```

Comment: @user3213304 the array holds two `Point`'s, the `Point`'s each have an `x` and a `y` so you have `array[0].x` `array[0].y` and `array[1].x` and `array[1].y`. You wouldn't say the array has "4 values" because it has 2 points and the points each have 2 values. You can have an array of any type so saying the array has 4 values because the points each have two does not make sense. I could have a `File[]` or a `string[]` or a `double[]`. The number of items in the array is independent from the properties of the types it contains.

Comment: @user3213304 also there a examples of loops. I don't know how you want to multiply the values. If you just wanted to apply that equation you have to all the items in the array or list, yes it would be easy enough. But I don't think that would really make sense to do so I'd need more explanation of what you want to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks, you explained everything really well.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to declare a class and Here it is:

```
public class Rectangle 
{ 
   public Rectangle(Point left, Point right)
   {
        Left = left;
        Right = right;
   }

   private Point Left{get; set;} 

   private Point Right{get; set;}

   public double CalculateArea()
   {
        return (points[0].x - points[1].x)  * (points[0].y - points[1].y);
   }

}
```

And here is how you can use it:

```
var rec = new Rectangle(new Point(15,15), new Point(200,220));
var someResult = rec.CalculateArea();
```

Answer (score 0):

In general you would be better off refactoring your program to use Point arrays as it has more semantic meaning.

But if this is a true rectangle (not just any four sided shape, where you need four points instead of two), you can do this:

```
public double[] ConvertPointsToArray(Point topLeft, Point bottomRight)
{
    var points = new double[4];
    points[0] = topLeft.x;
    points[1] = topLeft.y;
    points[2] = bottomRight.x;
    points[3] = bottomRight.y;
    return points;
}
```

And then you can use the array like this:

```
var points = ConvertPointsToArray(left, right);
var value = (points[0] - points[2]) * (points[1] - points[3]);
```

But as you can see you have to know how the points are encoded in the array and it is easy to mess up.

A rectangle class with two points would be more useful.